# How do I run my PiGlow

Tags: python

After following the steps on [this page](https://github.com/Boeeerb/PiGlow). I did everything correctly and when I try to run the `test.py` file it says this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last) :
    File "test.py" , line 9, in <module>
      piglow = PiGlow()
    File "/home/pi/piglow/piglow.py" , line 30,in _init_
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried rebooting, and trying it multiple times. I also used the `ls` command. I don't have Twitter.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many times do you intent to ask the same question?

Comment: Why do you have to post so many similar questions in such a short amount of time?  Please have patience.  You can edit in information into questions you know.